# Unwind to another brach of segues in swift or Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, swift3, segue

I have a scenario like this:

```
        /-> C -> D \
A -> B -            -> G (Contain values of D and F, 
        \-> E -> F /
```

Basically at `G` I have a list of value produce by `D` and `F`, let us call `D1` and `F1`.

To create a new value from `G`, I have to just `unwind` to `B` and user can either choose branch `C` or `E` and continue to the end `G` with value of `D2` or `F2`, or he can `pop` back to `A`. Let us say the new value is `F2`, though `ABEFG`

Now I'm facing a problem, that is I want to edit the values at `G`, let us say `D1`.

I want to be able to pop back to `D` but also allow users `pop` back to `C` etc, but `D` is not in the workflow `ABEFG`.

My guess is that I have to back up to `B` and somehow prepare *multiple* segues up to `D` but I have no idea if this kind of workflow exists.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619899/swift-unwind-segue-when-multiple-view-controllers-lead-to-same-view?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no such way. The solution I found is

1. Find the instance of `B` in `navigationController!.viewControllers`
2. `popToViewController` `B`
3. Initiate `C` & `D` from Main storyboard with identifier (they are already deallocated anyway)
4. Setup some properties of `C` & `D` from `D1`
5. `pushViewController` `C` & `D`