# Is it possible to have multiple unwind segua

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, unwind-segue

Is it possible to have multiple unwind segue in same view controller , where one bottom can navigate to different views with different unwind segue.

Comment: What do you mean "one bottom"?  Do you mean a tab bar?

Comment: It only makes sense to trigger one segue at a time.  You can wire up multiple unwind segues and trigger them with `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`.  Control drag from viewController icon at top of VC to exit icon, choose the destination `@IBAction`, then find the segue in the *Document Outline* and assign it an identifier.  Repeat to create more segues.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple unwind segues from a single view controller, but the implementation of your segues to get to that view controller will determine how and where you can unwind.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619899/swift-unwind-segue-when-multiple-view-controllers-lead-to-same-view) and make sure you do a thorough search before asking a question as you will likely get the dupe hammer for this one.